# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'request')

Tags: javascript, sql-server, database, request

I'm having issues with something about 'request' function and I can't find the way to fix this. Every time I try to run the server and get the results from database, I got this error message instead:

```
return pool.request().query('SELECT * FROM Products', function (err, result) {
                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'request')
```

Is there something missing I should have on my JS files?

connection.js

```
const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');

const dbSettings = {
    user: '******',
    password: '******',
    server: "DESKTOP-*****\\SQLEXPRESS",
    database: 'webstore',
    driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
    options: {
        encrypt: true,  // for azure
    }
}

export async function getConnection() {
    try {
       
        const pool = await sql.connect(dbSettings); 

        return pool;

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    
}
```

products.controller.js

```
import {getConnection} from '../database/connection';

export const getProducts = async (req, res) => {
    
    const pool = await getConnection();
    const result = await pool.request().query('SELECT * FROM Products');
    
    console.log(result);

    res.json('products');
};
```

Comment: Guessing... are there any connection-related errors on the console? Seems like `getConnection()` failed, so `pool` is `undefined`.